# Images not showing in Next.js with Laravel API despite correct paths and configurations. What might be causing this issue?

Tags: laravel, image, next.js

I have a nextjs project with laravel API.

I can upload the title, description and image to the DB. The images are stored in `storage/app/products` folder after uploading.

In MySQL database under the image column, it says:

> products/SNoCY9PG7BCoCMeWbkMNQgbV5CbpkTeR1V4oY4C2.jpg

ProductFeed.js

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Product from './Product'
import banner from '../../images/banner.jpg'
import Image from 'next/image'
import axios from 'axios'

const ProductFeed = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchdata()
    }, [])

    async function fetchdata() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api')
            setData(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Error')
        }
    }

  return (
    <div className='grid grid-flow-row-dense md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 md:-mt-52 mx-auto'> 
        {data.map(({ id, title, price, description, category, image }) => (
            <Product 
                key={id}
                id={id}
                title={title}
                price={price}
                description={description}
                category={category}
                image={image}
                // image={`http://localhost:8000/storage/app/${image}`}

/>
))}

        // <Image className='md:col-span-full' src={banner} alt='' />
    </div>
)
}

export default ProductFeed
```

Product.js

```
import Image from 'next/legacy/image'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { StarIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/solid'
import Currency from 'react-currency-formatter';
import prime from '../../images/prime.png'

const Product = ({ id, title, price, description, category, image }) => {

    return (
        <div className='relative flex flex-col m-5 bg-white z-30 p-10'>
            <p className='absolute -top-2 right-2 text-xs italic text-gray-400 my-3'>{category}</p>

            <Image
                src={image}
                height={200} width={200} 
            />

            <h4>{title}</h4>

            <p className='text-sm my-2 line-clamp-2'>{description}</p>

            <div className='mb-5'>
                {/* currency is USD by default */}
                <Currency quantity={price} /> 
            </div>

            <button onClick={() => (addToCart({
                id,
                title,
                description,
                price,
                category,
                image,
                hasPrime,
                rating,
                quantity: 1,
            }))} className='mt-auto button'>Add to Basket</button>

        </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

I have run `php artisan storage:link` command as well.

I have the following code in my next.config file:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost', '127.0.0.1'],
  },
};
```

I can see the title, description and other things rendered on my page but the images are not being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the URL like this http://localhost:8000/storage/${image}

Comment: I set the image src in Product.js to src={ http://localhost:8000/storage/${image}} but it doesn't work.

Comment: I set the image src in Product.js to src={ localhost:8000/storage/${image}} but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try localhost:8000/${image}

Comment: No. It doesn't work.

Comment: Let me know if we can do anydesk?

Comment: The image problem has been solved. I used html image tag and it worked. I am having another problem with laravel sanctum. If you don't mind, do you think you can help me with laravel sanctum for api and spa authentication throught anydesk?

Comment: Sure, why not
Please describe the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77117064/laravel-sanctum-spa-authentication-401-error-with-reactjs-and-laravel-api-and-ap

Comment: I added the link to the question I asked. Thank you.